# Overflow when uint64 = uint8 * uint8

Tags: c++

I try the below code:

```
UINT a = 32768;
UINT b = 32768;
UINT64 c = a * b * 4;  // c = 0,  overflow...;
UINT64 d = (UINT64)a * (UINT64)b * 4;  // d = 4294967296, the right answer;
```

why UINT64 c = a * b * 4 would be overflow?

I think a * b * 4 would first keep in a temp UINT value, then assign to the parameter c ? Is it right?

I want to search google for some hint, but I don't know what key word I should use.

Thanks

Comment: [Arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Comment: Your assumption is right. The whole operation is not atomic.

Comment: It would help if you used standard types. What is UINT?

Comment: And `uint8`? And how does `UINT` relate to `uint8` and `32768`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same reason for which

```
double x=1/2;
```

will be 0, but

```
double y=double(1)/2;
```

will be `0.5`.

Unless you force one of your operands to the desired final type, everything will be computed in the largest precision of any of the operands and only after that converted to the target type.

In you case, everything is computed in 32 bit precision, the overflow occurs *before* the conversion to 64bits.

Answer (score 3):

```
UINT a = 32768;
UINT b = 32768;
UINT64 c = a * b * 4;
```

is evaluated as

```
UINT a = (UINT) 32768;
UINT b = (UINT) 32768;
UINT64 c = (UINT) a * (UINT) b * (int) 4;
```

When `UINT` has not enough space to store `UINT*UINT`, you get an overflow.

You can fix this by casting one of the `UINT`s to an `UINT64` like so:

```
UINT64 c = (UINT64) a * b * 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the uint64 of c, it's right hand side is automatically assigned as an uint, because A and B are both uint, afterwards it assigns the answer to c (Already overflowed). To make sure this doesn't happen, ONE of the variables in c must be uint64 as well, and then it won't overflow.
Thats why int64 d works, because it was also assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct.  Because a and b are UINT values, the operation is done as a UINT and during a*b*4 which is 2^32 it overflows in a 32-bit UINT as 0.  The result is only then cast to a UINT64.